# swift image picker not closing after selecting an image

Tags: swift

I can open the image library and select a image but when I select a image the select of cancel section does not close. Am I missing something?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {

    var imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePickerController.delegate = self
    imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum
    imagePickerController.allowsEditing = true
    self.presentViewController(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: { imageP in

        })
}


func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: NSDictionary!) {
    let selectedImage : UIImage = image
    println(selectedImage)
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to dismiss view controller in

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: NSDictionary!) {
let selectedImage : UIImage = image
println(selectedImage)
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You are using the completion block on `presentViewController` improperly.

```
@IBAction func share(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
  let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
  imagePicker.delegate = self
  imagePicker.sourceType = .SavedPhotosAlbum
  presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Then use the delegate call to dismiss the picker.

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: NSDictionary!) {
  let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as UIImage
  dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```